# Thumbs on line corner points do not relocate points

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing a drawing application in which one can draw various types of lines. On the line corner points I have placed a thumb using an itemsControl. The thumbs should move that corner point when the user left mouse clicks on it and drags the mouse. What's happening now is that when I do this the point and thumb move a little bit, but then it loses mouse capture right away and doesn't move anymore. When I debug the first dragdelta event that gets fired correctly has a full visual tree traced up from the sending thumb to the itemscontrol and beyond, but sometimes when it fires the next time, the thumb's location has not been updated, and the containing content presenter has null parents in the visual tree.

This is the portion of the xaml related to the line thumb points:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PART_LineRelocate" ItemsSource="{Binding pointsObservableCollection}"  Visibility="Collapsed" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type s:LineCornerPoint}" >
           <Grid>
              <c:PointRelocateThumb VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Focusable="True"  x:Name="PART_PointRelocateThumb" Cursor="Hand"/>
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
     <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle >
         <Style > 
            <Style.Triggers>
                  <DataTrigger Value="BrokenLinkLine" Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type s:ToolLine}}, Path=indicator}" >
                      <Setter  Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Corner.X}" />
                      <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Corner.Y}"   />
                  </DataTrigger>

                     ....More of these datatriggers for the different types of lines
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
   </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The code for PointRelocateThumb:

```
 public PointRelocateThumb()
    {

        base.DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(this.PointRelocateThumb_DragDelta);

    }
    void PointRelocateThumb_DragDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        PointRelocateThumb prt = (PointRelocateThumb)sender;
        LineCornerPoint lcp = (LineCornerPoint)prt.DataContext;
        Point thumbPoint = new Point(Canvas.GetLeft((ContentPresenter)prt.TemplatedParent), Canvas.GetTop((ContentPresenter)prt.TemplatedParent));
        ToolLine toolLine = null;
        DrawingCanvas designer = null;
        ItemsControl itemsControl = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(prt.TemplatedParent);
        if (itemsControl != null)
            toolLine = itemsControl.DataContext as ToolLine;
        if (toolLine != null)
            designer = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(toolLine) as DrawingCanvas;
        if (toolLine != null && designer != null && toolLine.IsSelected)
        {
            thumbPoint = new Point(thumbPoint.X + Canvas.GetLeft(toolLine) + 3.5, thumbPoint.Y + Canvas.GetTop(toolLine) + 3.5);

            toolLine.undoBounding();
            if (System.String.Compare(toolLine.indicator, "BrokenLinkLine") == 0
                || System.String.Compare(toolLine.indicator, "LinkLine") == 0
                || System.String.Compare(toolLine.indicator, "OrthogonalLinkLine") == 0
                || System.String.Compare(toolLine.indicator, "BrokenLine") == 0
                || System.String.Compare(toolLine.indicator, "Line") == 0
                || System.String.Compare(toolLine.indicator, "Polygon") == 0)
            {
                if (toolLine.pathFigure.StartPoint.Equals(thumbPoint))
                {
                    toolLine.pathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(modifyingToolLine.pathFigure.StartPoint.X + e.HorizontalChange, modifyingToolLine.pathFigure.StartPoint.Y + e.VerticalChange);                    }
                else
                {
                    foreach (LineSegment ls in toolLine.pathSegmentCollection)

                    {
                        if (ls.Point.Equals(thumbPoint))
                        {
                            ls.Point = new Point(ls.Point.X + e.HorizontalChange, ls.Point.Y + e.VerticalChange);
                            break;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
           toolLine.regenerateBoundingItem();
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    } 
 }
```

}

Tooline is the line class. What undo binding does is that it makes it so that toolLine has Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top set to 0, but scales the points so that they are still located at the same point - i.e. by adding the old Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top values of the toolLine to each point in the line.

The code for regenerate Bounding item is below:

```
public void regenerateBoundingItem()
{
     //Following line of code just regenerates the underlying path for the toolLine from the 
     //new pathsegmentCollection and pathFigure start point.  
    regenerateThisLine();
    double leftMostPoint = double.MaxValue, topMostPoint = double.MaxValue, bottomMostPoint = double.MinValue, rightMostPoint = double.MinValue;
    getBoundingPoints(ref leftMostPoint, ref topMostPoint, ref bottomMostPoint, ref rightMostPoint);

     //subtracts leftMost point and topMostPoint from each point in the line
     scaleLinePoints(leftMostPoint, topMostPoint); 
     Canvas.SetLeft(this, leftMostPoint);
     Canvas.SetTop(this, topMostPoint);
     this.Width = rightMostPoint - leftMostPoint;
     this.Height = bottomMostPoint-topMostPoint;
      regenerateObservableCollection();
      regenerateThisLine();
}
private void regenerateObservableCollection()
{
    if (this.pointsObservableCollection == null)
        this.pointsObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<LineCornerPoint>();
    this.pointsObservableCollection.Clear();
    LineCornerPoint startPt = new LineCornerPoint(new Point(this.pathFigure.StartPoint.X - 3.5, this.pathFigure.StartPoint.Y - 3.5));
    this.pointsObservableCollection.Add(startPt);
    if (System.String.Compare(indicator, "BrokenLine") == 0
        || System.String.Compare(indicator, "BrokenLinkLine") == 0
        || System.String.Compare(indicator, "LinkLine") == 0
        || System.String.Compare(indicator, "Polygon") == 0
       || System.String.Compare(indicator, "Line") == 0)
    {
        foreach (LineSegment ls in pathSegmentCollection)
        {
            LineCornerPoint pt = new LineCornerPoint(new Point(ls.Point.X - 3.5, ls.Point.Y - 3.5));
            this.pointsObservableCollection.Add(pt);
         }
     }
}
```

The template for PointRelocateThumb is an ellipse of width and height 7 - which explains why I have to offset all the thumb locations by 3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with regenerateObserableCollection

Instead of clearing and destroying all the LineCornerObjects, I had to modify the LineCornerPoints contained in the observable collection.